# ASP.NET MVC Rotativa ViewAsPDF vastly different between debug and production

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, rotativa

I am using Rotativa ViewAsPdf to turn a `.cshtml` page into PDF.

When I run the code as debug, the PDF turns out the way I want. The page has tables and an image on the top.

Whenever I publish the application and try to generate the PDF as a different entry, the tables lines that separate columns from rows aren't there, and everything is mashed together, and the image will not display.

This is the POST details in question.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PrintDetails(int? id) 
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
            
    var wC_Inbox = await _context.WC_Inbox
                                 .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);

    var report = new ViewAsPdf("Details", wC_Inbox)
                     {
                         FileName = "InitialInbox.pdf"
                     };
    return report;
}
```

Here are the differences between the two PDFs that get generated. The one on the left is what is generated when running on debug, and the one on the right is the messed up one that gets generated on the production.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/b14nb.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please could you clarify what you mean exactly by "debug" and "production"? In each scenario, are you hosting the application in IIS or IIS Express? Is the build configuration set to Debug or Release? Is the application hosted on your development machine (i.e. the one you're using to write the code) or some other server (and if some other server, how is it deployed)? Which combinations of the above have you tried, and in each case did it produce the desired result or not? This will help to narrow down what might be causing the problem.

Comment: @sbridewell The application is hosted on some other server, but I do not mess with it in much capacity other than publishing applications to it (Build -> Publish "appName" in visual studio). By debug, I mean just running the code locally, and it was not IIS Express. I switched the Run dropdown to IIS Express to try printing the PDF and it did have the same issue where The tables didn't show and everything was mashed together.